# gradle: how to access the gradle.properties from another project

Tags: gradle

How can I access a `gradle.properties` from another project?

```
project1/gradle.properties

project2
```

Project2 uses the same `gradle.properties` as Project1. The `gradle.properties` is in source control, so it is not good idea to put it in user home directory.

The `gradle.properties` of Project1 contains some credentials I would like to reuse in Project2.

Is there a way to tell Gradle the location of `gradle.properties`?

Comment: whats in your gradle.properties that you want to share on these 2 builds?

Comment: username, password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its a very good idea to put username & password into a version control system. Your user home is the place to store your credentials. 
Make sure the users home `gradle.properties` can only be read by your user processes. On a Unix like operating system this would be:

```
chmod 600 ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Furthermore creating dependency between repositories sharing a `gradle.properties` feels like the wrong approach. This is why Gradle introduced the user home `gradle.properties`.

But if you still think it is a good idea and/or you don't have any other choice you can set `-Dgradle.user.home=project1` and it will pick up the `gradle.properties` from Project1.