# How to include variables from another gradle.properties file?

Tags: gradle

Gradle v2.9.x (old I know, but that's another project)

I tried the solution suggested in [gradle: how to access the gradle.properties from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789488/gradle-how-to-access-the-gradle-properties-from-another-project) to no avail.

I want to define artifact versions on a top-level `gradle.properties` file like so

```
toplevel/gradle.properties file:
artifact1_version='1.0.0'
```

Then I want to be able to use the above variable in `artifact1_version` variable like so

```
toplevel/artifact1/gradle.properties file:
version="$artifact1_version"
```

Is this possible to do in Gradle? If so how? I come from the Maven world so sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is put the variables in the build.gradle files, like this.

```
toplevel/build.gradle file:
ext.artifact1_version='1.0.0'
```

Then in the subprojects, do

```
toplevel/artifact1/build.gradle file:
version="$parent.artifact1_version"
```